# Exercise to determine $\mathcal{O}_K$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> *Exercise:* Let $p$ and $q$ be prime with $p \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$ and $ q \equiv 3 \bmod{4}$. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})$, determine $\mathcal{O}_K$.

I'm stuck with this exercise. As a basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$, I used $B = \bigl(1, \sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q}, \sqrt{p q}\bigr)$, this gives me the discriminant $\Delta_B = 256\cdot p^2\cdot q^2$. Now I used
$$x = \frac{1}{2} \bigl(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 \sqrt{p} + \lambda_3 \sqrt{q} +\lambda_4 \sqrt{p q}\bigr)$$ with $\lambda_i \in \{0, 1\}$ and at least one $\lambda_i = 1$, if I can find an integer element $x$. But the whole thing is so complicated, there has to be an easier way.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check Proposition 2.11 in Neukirch - Algebraic Number Theory. This states that we obtain an integral basis of such an extension by just multiplying the two integral bases, provided their discrimants are co-prime.

Comment: I would have started with the basis $\{1,(1+\sqrt p)/2\}$ and then passed to the biquadratic ring, till I read the helpful comment of @MooS. You should certainly use what you know about quadratic fields here... And did you look at the case of $3$ and $5$?